# Why was the 2020 Election Nomination Period Extended?

Tags: support, election

The nominations were supposed to end today (June 22th), but they have been extended for another week, why?

Answer (score 6):

The nomination period for the 2020 election on Photography has been extended for a week so that we can have more nominations. While the existing nominations are appreciated, for this to election to move forward, it must be competitive - meaning there must be more nominees than there are slots. As this is a two-slot election, that means that three nominees are necessary for the election to move forward.

We have one person who has nominated on the election page and one additional person has added their responses to the questionnaire. If that second person nominates, we need only one additional nominee for this election to move forward to the voting phase next week. Please take this time to think about whether you're interested in stepping up to support this site as a moderator or - if you know of someone who would be a great moderator here - feel free to encourage them to nominate. Sometimes people don't realize how good a fit they'd be.

The schedule now is:

- June 29th: Nomination ends and voting begins
- July 7th: Voting ends and results are announced

If we do not manage to get to 3 candidates by the 29th, this will have to be considered a failed election - in which case we'll discuss with the community what might've happened and when to set up a new one, then try again. Too many consecutive failed elections can make a site up for closure.

Comment: "Too many consecutive failed elections can make a site up for closure" I hope this doesn't happen. I only joined a week ago but this does seem like a nice place to be around. If I had been around longer, I would nominate myself simply because I don't want to see this place disappear.

Comment: The two candidates nominated so far are both solid members of this community and would both likely do well as moderators. It's shame we can't hold elections as straight up "yes/no" votes when two quality candidates are nominated.

Comment: Romeo expressed interest, so hopefully he'll put his name in officially.

Comment: I might have thrown my hat in the ring (while praying to *not* be elected) just to enable an election if I had been able to find where to do that.

Comment: It seems to be *the design* that one must be [on the ball](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/77043/282094) and fully engaged to participate in elections: don't visit <s>regularly</s> daily, missed the meta, busy during a pandemic - you're out. But now that we're not choosy beggars shouldn't we lighten up, or extend a little longer. We get notifications that the election starts (if Chat doesn't push them out, those *pingers*!) but [seemingly none](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qhkvn.jpg) for an election extension.

Answer (score 2):

The two candidates nominated so far are both solid members of this community and would both likely do well as moderators. It's shame we can't hold elections as straight up "yes/no" votes with two quality candidates.